# Loading project file on AWS S3 giving error 403: Forbidden

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have uploaded to AWS basic app where I am loading few assets. For some reason these models are throwing this error:

Error: fetch for “https:…/model1.glb” responded with 403: Forbidden

I have uploaded few test apps to AWS before without any issues. Bucket policy is setup and permissions are all public.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ts1/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit: the app was built with Vite and I am hosting dist folder

Comment: Any chance you have [Block Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html) set at bucket or account level? Also, FYI your policy does more than permit unauthenticated downloads. It also allows unauthenticated uploads, which is is almost always a very bad idea.

Comment: @jarmod The bucket has public access allowed. I have tested it on other buckets as well, which already worked on other apps, but not this one. No idea what is causing this error. You are talking about the action PutObject right? It was just something I tried to test if it helps. I found it somewhere on AWS support page. Otherwise I use only GetObject.

Comment: Additional troubleshooting steps [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403). Is the object actually owned by the AWS account that owns the S3 bucket? Are there any organization level SCPs for S3? Is this S3 object KMS-encrypted? Is the bucket configured with Requester Pays?

Comment: @jarmod Thanks, I will have a look there. I have no idea what most of those things you said are, so probably no to all of that. The object is actually local in the project. Ie it's just a file inside the project uploaded along with the project, but for whatever reason AWS is throwing this error. There are no issues/errors when running it locally, the file loads fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "There are no issues/errors when running it locally"? Running what locally? Do you mean a Node.js fetch of the S3 URL `https://ts1.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/model1.glb`?

Comment: @jarmod It's a Vite project, the file is inside this project. When I run it on local server through Node the file loads no issues. When I upload this project to AWS under public access bucket, it throws error when loading this file. Which makes no sense to me, because this file is in that project. It's not external URL, the whole project is on S3 bucket, all source code including this file. I am uploading dist folder ( build folder and all it's content ). So I don't know why AWS is blocking loading a file that is already in the project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was putting the file into public folder. I am loading the asset now from this path './assets/models/plant1.glb'. For whatever reason that was the whole issue, works now on AWS and Firebase hosting.

Comment: Don't forget the Origin header lol